# Easy modification to show the image instead of the url

Tags: php

How do I show the image instead of the url?

```
echo "<b>Image: </b> http://graph.facebook.com/" . $posts['from']['id'] ."/picture?type=large</br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `<img>` tag with `src` set to your url:

```
echo "<b>Image: </b> <img src='http://graph.facebook.com/"
      . $posts['from']['id'] ."/picture?type=large'></br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo "<b>Image: </b><img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" . $posts['from']['id'] ."/picture?type=large'/></br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/".$posts['from']['id'] 
         ."/picture?type=large">
```

This will build the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<b>Image: </b> <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' . $posts['from']['id'] . '/picture?type=large" /><br />';
```

Alternatively, without using concatenation:

```
<b>Image: </b> <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $posts['from']['id']; ?>/picture?type=large" /><br />
```

Or using short tags:

```
<b>Image: </b> <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?=$posts['from']['id']?>/picture?type=large" /><br />
```